# How to get String value from onBindViewHolder?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I use Recycleview for display my data from database.
my problem is when i want pass value to another activity.
this my code :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.gameName.setText(games.get(position).getGameName());
    holder.gamePublisher.setText(games.get(position).getGamePublisher());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return games.size();
}


public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView gameName,gamePublisher;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String value = gameName.toString();
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("value", value);
                ((Activity)v.getContext()).setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                ((Activity)v.getContext()).finish();
            }
        });
        gameName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.gamename);
        gamePublisher = itemView.findViewById(R.id.gamepublisher);
    }
}
```

and i got this from my EditText in another activity :

> androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView{63b682c V.Ed..... ...P... 0,0-1080,97# app:id/gamename}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
String value = gameName.toString();
```

to

```
String value = gameName.getText().toString();
```

first line will send a `View` "shorted" to `String` (so you can see some hash, `View` class, size etc.), you need only text in this field, so `getText()`

Comment: oh beginner's mistake, this small problem make me crazy, thank you for helping... ^__^